# Проблема с header при попытке отдать на скачивание содержимое переменной

Tags: php, http

Нужно отдать содержание переменной как *.txt* файл пользователю на скачивание.

Пытаюсь делать это так:

```
ob_start();
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=logs.txt');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($file));
echo $file;
ob_get_clean();
```

Но в итоге ничего не происходит.

Хотелось бы узнать - как можно нормально отдать информацию в моем случае?

Comment: А зачем вам `Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary`? И что вы подразумеваете, под тем, что `ничего не происходит`?

Comment: @VladimirSerykh с буферизацией файл не отдается вообще. Без буферизации говорит, что заголовки уже отправлены и модифицировать их нельзя, а содержимое просто выводится на экран.

Comment: Если вам пишут, что `заголовки уже отправлены и модифицировать их нельзя`, то поищите проблему в другом месте. Значит, до этого момента уже пошёл вывод контента.

Comment: @VladimirSerykh до этого момента ничего не выводится. А только проверяется сессия.

Comment: @Виталий RS проверьте в файлах скрипта наличие BOM. Проблема может быть в нём.

Comment: @ВиталийRS Ещё в скриптах, которые ничего не выводят, стоит опускать закрывающий PHP-тэг `?>`, чтобы концы строк и пробелы не попадали в аутпут.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   function file_force_download($file) {
      if (file_exists($file)) {
        // сбрасываем буфер вывода PHP, чтобы избежать переполнения памяти выделенной под скрипт
        // если этого не сделать файл будет читаться в память полностью!
        if (ob_get_level()) {
          ob_end_clean();
        }
        // заставляем браузер показать окно сохранения файла
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        // читаем файл и отправляем его пользователю
        readfile($file);
        exit;
      }
    }
```