# Записывается код, а не содержимое

Tags: php, html

Имеются данные в базе, которые выводятся вот таким образом:

**values1.php**

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
if (!$con) die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("test", $con);
$data = mysql_query("SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`time`) AS ts, value FROM sensor1") or die ("Query error");
$V0  = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
$V0 .= sprintf( ' %u %f', $row['ts'], $row['value']);
}
mysql_close($con);
echo sprintf( '%s', strip_tags($V0));
?>
<?php
```

На сайте по кнопке данные сохраняются в файл. Пытаюсь реализовать через вот такой PHP код, но в скачанном файле сам код, а не содержимое базы данных.

```
<?php 
$file = 'values1.php';
if (isset($_GET['down'])) { 
if ($_GET['down'] == $file) { 
    if (!is_file($file)) {
        echo "Файл <b>$file</b> не найден<br />\n";
    } else {
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file"); 
        header("Content-type: application/octet-stream"); 
        $qwe = file_get_contents($file); 
    echo $qwe;
        exit;
    }
} else {
    echo "Файл $file не разрешен для скачивания<br>\n";
}
} else {
echo "<a href='?down=$file'> Скачать файл </a><br />\n"; 
}
?>
```

Подскажите, как сохранить именно данные?

Comment: сохраните в tmp фаил результат и потом берите его.

Comment: попробуй заменить file_get_contents на include

P.S. file_get_contents не исполняет, а только забирает содержимое файла

Comment: [Возможно, тут есть решение Вашей проблемы?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/434679/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-header-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9)